# Samsung GALAXY Tab 10.1 sch-i905 stuck at the load screen

Tags: cyanogenmod, boot-loop, rom, unbricking, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

I have a *Galaxy Tab 10.1,* Model *SCH-i905/U* from us cellular (image1).

In order to root it, and after an internet search I flashed the device, corrupting files left and right. That's when it can't even start up anymore. It is stuck at the load screen Samsung GALAXY Tab 10.1 (image2).

[image] [[image][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgnsjm.jpg)
<sup>Click images for larger variants if needed :)</sup>

I have tried about every method on different forums and I am unable to find the factory firmware for this specific model or get it back to stock.

I can get to downloading mode and use Odin. The only file that this software show “PASS” on green is `PDA_SIGNED_P7105.tar.md5`. Before, it was just stuck at the boot screen with yellow triangle.

I followed the method with `PDA_HC31_EG01Ba_AP352081user_CP1033580_LTE20110704_0708.tar` but that was failed. Then it won't boot up and stays in infinite boot-looping on "Samsung" logo. I can't get to  fast-boot. recovery give me error message in image below:

[image: photo] [image: photo]
<sup>photos (click images for larger variants)</sup>

**Update:** I've already checked with [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575) Unfortunately, I still couldn't find a fitting ROM. All hints are welcome!

Comment: First place you might wish to look is [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)

Comment: We are not an email service, youssef, but a site collecting knowledge. I gave you the link where you can find the original firmware. Have you checked that?

Comment: At first, Thank you Mr. Izzy for your assistance and feedback, I am sorry if I violate rules by posting E-mail. It’s first time that I am posting in forums.Secondly, I’ve followed the links you gave me and looked over the web looking for info related to this U.S. Cellular device; I can't find any specifics things. Thanks if you can be more helpful, and point me in the proper direction, it would be most appreciated.

Comment: Sorry if no matching source was found behind that link. Of course, we cannot claim to have a complete listing (as that's impossible). I'll update your question to reflect the fact (you know, you always can [edit] it); with some luck, there will be someone else to help you out. I'm from Europe, so I'm not that familiar with US services. // To get most out of our site, you might wish to browse our [help] – won't take much more than 10 minutes to get the basics there. Good luck further!

Comment: OK, thanks again.if I'm lucky there will be someone!!